# Interpreting signed and unsigned numbers

Tags: binary, twos-complement

the teacher told us that a binary number, for examle 1000 0001, have 2 meanings. one is represent -127 (signed), which is from -127 to 127
and the another is a unsigned number , from 0 to 256

If I have a number in binary, for example 1000 0001 , the calculator shows only the signed number (-127). how can I know what is the unsigned number that this binary number represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A signed and an unsigned number *have exactly the same bits*!

In your calculator, you can display as hex (0xff).  It's up to you whether you want to interpret the hex digits and "signed" or "unsigned".

In x86 assembler, you can check the "sign bit" in the CPU status flags.

Check out this tutorial:

[Signed vs Unsigned Numbers](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2008/fall/cs301/lecture/10_17_signed_unsigned.html)

Comment: my question is , if I have a specific binary number ,for example 1000 0001, how can I know the 2 interaptions for this number?

Comment: 1) Please read the link I cited.  2) Please understand that in terms of the "binary arithmetic", *THERE IS NO DIFFERENCE*.  3) In terms of mentally converting between signed and unsigned: a) UNSIGNED: just add the bits (0x81 == 129); b) SIGNED: if the high bit is set, then SUBTRACT the remaining bits from 128 (here, 128-1 -> -127).

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned numbers are the easiest to interpret from binary; simply add all the values that the bits represent (`2^7+2^0` in the case of the number `1000 0001` =129).

The signed interpretation is pretty much the same, except for one extra step first:
If the leading digit is `1`, then you invert all the bits (in this case `0111 1110`) and add `1` to the result to get the (absolute) value of the negative number (in this case `0111 1111`=127)

To test that you did it correctly, do the same operation again and you should end up with the original number.

Comment: Or more simply, the place-value of the sign bit is `-128` for 2's complement instead of `+128` for unsigned.  (Assuming 8-bit numbers).  You're describing how to do 2's complement negation to get an unsigned number.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're pointing out?
In the first paragraph I describe how to read (unsigned) binary numbers, and in the second I describe how to get the absolute value of a (negative) signed number using 2's complement - that's how you decode binary, is it not? Of course I could (and possibly should) have added a (-) in front to make it explicit, but I did say *absolute value* of the negative number, so I thought it was implied.

Comment: Sure you could follow that rule to get the sign and magnitude of a 2's complement encoded number.  Or you could just look at it as the bits having a place value of `2^n`, except for the top bit having a place value of `-(2^n)`.  I find that simpler: you can think about the meaning of the 2's complement encoding directly, instead of only in terms of taking the absolute value using a 2-step process.  i.e. it's immediately visible that `1000 0000` has a value of `-128`, without having to think through `0x7f + 1`